# Function call for second time causing segementation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have been trying to execute this following C program. This program executes without any compliation error , however it gives out a "Segmentation Fault" error message.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node
{
    char str[100];
    struct Node *children[100];
    int numc;
    int isd;
};

void _strsearch(struct Node *node, char *name, char *res)
{
    int i = 0;
    char cpy[200];
    strcpy(cpy, res);
    if (strcmp(node->str, "") != 0)
        strcat(cpy, "/");
    strcat(cpy, node->str);
    for (; i < node->numc; i++)
    {
        _strsearch(node->children[i], name, cpy);
        strcpy(cpy, res);
        if (strcmp(node->str, "") != 0)
            strcat(cpy, "/");
        strcat(cpy, node->str);
    }
    if (strcmp(name, node->str) == 0)
    {
        strcat(res, "/");
        strcat(res, node->str);
        if (node->isd)
            strcat(res, "/");
        printf(" %s ", res);
    }
}

void strsearch(struct Node *tree, char *name)
{
    char path[200];
    strcpy(path, tree->str);
    _strsearch(tree, name, path);
}

struct Node *create_root()
{
    struct Node *t = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    strcpy(t->str, "");
    t->numc = 0;
    t->isd = 0;
    return t;
}

struct Node *add_node(struct Node *tree, char *name, int isd)
{
    struct Node *t = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node *));
    strcpy(t->str, name);
    t->numc = 0;
    t->isd = isd;
    tree->children[tree->numc] = t;
    tree->numc += 1;
    return tree;
}

struct Node* del_node(struct Node *tree, char *name)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < tree->numc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(tree->children[i]->str, name) == 0)
        {
            for (j = i; j < tree->numc - 1; j++)
                tree->children[j] = tree->children[j + 1];

            tree->numc -= 1;
            i -= 1;
        }
    }
    return tree;
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *tree;
    struct Node *t;
    tree = create_root();
    tree = add_node(tree, "ay", 0);
    tree = add_node(tree, "by", 0);
    t = tree->children[0];
    t = add_node(t, "by", 1);
    t = t->children[0];
    t = add_node(t, "by", 0);
    t = add_node(t, "gy", 0);
    strsearch(tree, "by"); // line 1
    strsearch(tree, "by"); // line 2
    return 0;
}
```

This program gives desired output when I fully comment out 'line 2'.
Why does this happen? Both function calls are the same with same parameters. And (according to me) the function `_strsearch()` does not change any values of the parameters. Can someone help me in identifying the actual cause for this behaviour?

Output (which is correct) when 'line 2' is commented:

```
 /ay/by/by  /ay/by/  /by
```

Comment: I can see this output `/ay/by/by  /ay/by/  /by  /ay/by/by  /ay/by/  /by` without commenting line 2. What you are expecting ?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger like GDB? It may help you to identify on which line the program crashes.

Comment: Since both the function calls are the same, I am supposed to get the same output like what you are getting. But instead, I am getting "Segmentation Fault". @Achal

Comment: I am using GCC complier which one are you using? @Achal?

Comment: @kinder_shah I used GDB for trying to get the secific statement causing the problem. But it wasn't showing out the particular line. It was only giving out output as well as the SIGSEGV error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrespective of what output you are expecting ther are few things which needs to be corrected.

Firstly *initialize below char buffer*. For example

```
 char path[200] = {0}; /* zerod whole buffer */
 char cpy[200] = {0};
```

Secondly, in the `add_node()` function, memory allocation should be

```
struct Node *t = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); /* number of bytes should be equal to size of struct Node */
```

instead of

```
struct Node *t = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node *));
```

And do check the return value of `malloc()`. For example

```
struct Node *t = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
if(t == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

Here is the [live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/B1PBzOIEr)

Comment: It worked. Just had to provide ''struct Node" instead of "struct Node *". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On function `add_node` you allocate memory for a pointer instead of a full node.
Your code:

```
struct Node *t = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node *));
```

Correct code:

```
struct Node *t = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

and full working code (Compiled and tested with MS Visual Studio 2019):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node
{
    char str[100];
    struct Node* children[100];
    int numc;
    int isd;
};

void _strsearch(struct Node* node, const char* name, char* res)
{
    int i = 0;
    char cpy[200];
    strcpy(cpy, res);
    if (strcmp(node->str, "") != 0)
        strcat(cpy, "/");
    strcat(cpy, node->str);
    for (; i < node->numc; i++)
    {
        _strsearch(node->children[i], name, cpy);
        strcpy(cpy, res);
        if (strcmp(node->str, "") != 0)
            strcat(cpy, "/");
        strcat(cpy, node->str);
    }
    if (strcmp(name, node->str) == 0)
    {
        strcat(res, "/");
        strcat(res, node->str);
        if (node->isd)
            strcat(res, "/");
        printf(" %s ", res);
    }
}

void strsearch(struct Node* tree, const char* name)
{
    char path[200];
    strcpy(path, tree->str);
    _strsearch(tree, name, path);
}

struct Node* create_root()
{
    struct Node* t = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    strcpy(t->str, "");
    t->numc = 0;
    t->isd = 0;
    return t;
}

struct Node* add_node(struct Node* tree, const char* const name, int isd)
{
    struct Node* t = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    strcpy(t->str, name);
    t->numc = 0;
    t->isd = isd;
    tree->children[tree->numc] = t;
    tree->numc += 1;
    return tree;
}

struct Node* del_node(struct Node* tree, const char* const name)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < tree->numc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(tree->children[i]->str, name) == 0)
        {
            for (j = i; j < tree->numc - 1; j++)
                tree->children[j] = tree->children[j + 1];

            tree->numc -= 1;
            i -= 1;
        }
    }
    return tree;
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* tree;
    struct Node* t;
    tree = create_root();
    tree = add_node(tree, "ay", 0);
    tree = add_node(tree, "by", 0);
    t = tree->children[0];
    t = add_node(t, "by", 1);
    t = t->children[0];
    t = add_node(t, "by", 0);
    t = add_node(t, "gy", 0);
    strsearch(tree, "by"); // line 1
    strsearch(tree, "by"); // line 2
    return 0;
}
```